# Do AngularJS or Ember have a "client-side ID" concept (cid)?

Tags: angularjs, ember.js

Backbone has a concept of client-side IDs or `cid`s.

Does AngularJS?

Does Ember.js?

Comment: Can you confirm that by cids you mean HTML element IDs or something else.

Comment: @Ketan Something else. [Backbone defines `cid`s](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) as: “A special property of models, the cid or client id is a unique identifier automatically assigned to all models when they're first created. Client ids are handy when the model has not yet been saved to the server, and does not yet have its eventual true id, but already needs to be visible in the UI.”

Comment: OK. In that case I haven't encountered it so far in Angular.  I believe this is due to the MVC nature of the framework, where it takes care of the bindings between the View and Model. Even if the model is not saved, it is still visible on the view due to the bindings. Do you have a special use case? Maybe it is done differently in AngularJs.


I am not very familiar with Ember. I spent some time in Ember but was less intuitive to me than AngularJS. YMMV tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for Ember.js, yes it does have the your so called `client-side IDs` concept,
see here for reference: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js#L37

and also here https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L27-L40

Ember-data uses a property called `clientId` on the Model that is a transient numerical identifier generated at runtime by the data store when you do something like `App.MyModel.createRecord({...})`. This is obviously done because newly created records do not  have at creation time an server side generated id.

hope it helps

Comment: That seems to be the ember-data way so far. I'm trying to write an adapter for it and keep banging my head because I have to learn the way all of ember-data works before I can make it work.